# Potential security issues warning banners with Ethereum

Tags: security, ether

I'm testing ethereum and the foundation websites states that

> Frontier is an early access to the Ethereum network. Bugs and security
>   issues might be present. Before downloading you have to agree to the
>   terms that follow and the full terms linked below.

I understand `bugs` but what kind of `security` issues are they referencing to? That all ones ether can be lost? So far, I have not purchased any ether, so I guess even if I purposefully wanted to, I could not do anything that would be dangerous in any way. If anything else, what should I definitely *not* do before I understand the technology better?

Answer (score 1):

We are very close to the Homestead release when the Ethereum Foundation (I believe) will take away a lot of the "WARNING! Potential bugs and security issues!" type of messages or at least be fewer from what I understand.

If someone lost ether to a programming bug, I think we'd see it very widely publicized (so it could be analyzed and fixed), but thus far I've not heard of this happening. (Other than UI / user error type stuff, people fat fingering addresses and sending money to address zero by mistake for instance. Both of these can be mitigated by sending small amounts first.)

> If anything else, what should I definitely not do before I understand
>   the technology better?

It's easier to describe some of the things you *should* do than not do. Do use stable versions (unless you're a developer and like to live on the cutting edge or you want to see what's coming up in terms of features). Do keep up to date with announcements from the Ethereum Foundation. (Stack Exchange, the Ethereum subreddit, their blog, etc.) Do be paranoid of people or websites asking for keys / files / changing settings in a weird way. If it feels weird, Stack Exchange is definitely a good place to ask as a sanity check. (As long as the question isn't already answered.)